# Less expensive way of converting a double[] to an immutable list

Tags: java, arrays, list, immutable-collections

I want to convert an array `double[]` to an immutable collection for use in a value object. However, I am dealing with a very large array and I keep getting the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

I am currently using

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(DoubleStream.of(myArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I think it is because of this my program is running out of memory. Is there a cheaper way to convert double[] to an immutable list?

Comment: Double is a double. If you don't have enough memory to store e.g. a million doubles, then you can't store a million doubles. There is no trick to get around that.

Comment: The problem isn't (presumably) storing a million doubles, they're already stored in `myArray`, the problem is duplicating the space by streaming the array and creating a copy of the elements. A `List` wrapping the existing array would require no additional space.

Comment: What about `Arrays.asList(myArray)`?

Comment: @Sweeper Where `myArray` is type `double[]`, you cannot do that. It would need to be `Double[]`

Comment: So I have to ask – why is your `double[]` *that* large? For what do you need it? I ask that because there *may be* other ways than storing a huge array.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating your own `List<Double>`? If you implement `AbstractList<Double>`, you'd only need to implement two methods for an unmodifiable list:

```
class MyDoubleList extends AbstractList<Double> implements RandomAccess {

    private double[] backingArray;

    public MyDoubleList(double[] backingArray) {
        this.backingArray = backingArray;
    }

    @Override
    public Double get(int index) {
        return backingArray[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return backingArray.length;
    }

    // adding other list methods should be trivial...
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Double> list = new MyDoubleList(myBigDoubleArray);
```

Note that if you change the backing array, the list contents will change as well. To prevent this, you'd usually copy the array passed in, but since copying the array will probably cause an out of memory exception, I didn't do it.

---

Or if you use Guava, use [`Doubles.asList(myBigDoubleArray)`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#asList-double...-), which does essentially the same thing. Thanks to Joe for the suggestion!

Comment: This is essentially Guava's [`Doubles.asList`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#asList-double...-), which would probably be preferable to use instead.

Comment: @Joe Didn't know I reinvented the wheel there! I don't usually use things like Guava...

Comment: Nice solution.  I think I'll tuck this away for future reference. +1

Answer (score 0):

Streams are great for functional programming, and readability but should be avoided when performance is the main concern. They create unnecessary extra objects.

Also surprisingly, arrays of the double primitive types consume more memory than their wrapper class Double arrays (ref: https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives-vs-objects)

Use a `Double` object array instead of a double primitive, and then run:

```
Collection<Double> l = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

I compared the 2 approaches like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int len = 1000000;
        Double[] myArray = new Double[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            myArray[i] = Math.random();
        }
        Collection<Double> l = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(myArray));
        long totalMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        long usedMem =  totalMem - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("totalMem="+humanReadableByteCountBin(totalMem));
        System.out.println("usedMem=" + humanReadableByteCountBin(usedMem));
        System.out.println("l has " + l.size() + " items ");
    }
```

The stream approach used 48Mb, whereas `Arrays.asList` with Double uses 28Mb.